# Added values wont save to malloc array correctly. Is there a memory leak I am overlooking?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, struct, malloc, realloc

I am trying to save values to a dynamically allocated array of structs. The program works fine inside the for loop where malloc is called and prints the values correctly but once the for loop ends and I try to print again it seg faults.

This is the header with the struct definitions

```
 typedef struct{
  char student_name[100];
  int stdnt_id;
  int courses[4];
  int grades[4][10];
  int number_courses;
  }students;

typedef struct{
  char course_name[100];
  int course_id;
  int course_students[100];
  int number_students;
  }courses;

typedef struct{             
  int number_courses;                           
  int number_students;
  }useful_numbers;
```

And this is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structures.h"

useful_numbers numbers;
students **student;
courses **course;

void add_course(void)
{
putchar('\n');
int x, y, z, new, tmp;
printf("How many courses are you adding? ");
scanf("%d", &new);
getchar();
tmp=numbers.number_courses;
if(numbers.number_courses>0)
    {
    courses **course=(courses **)realloc(course, sizeof(courses *)*(new+numbers.number_courses));
    if(NULL==course)
        {
        printf("There was a problem in malloc\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    for(x=tmp; x<new+tmp; x++)
        {
        course[x]=(courses *)malloc(sizeof(courses));
        if(NULL==course[x])
            {
            printf("There was a problem in malloc\n");
            exit(2);
            }
        printf("Print the name of course number %d: ", x+1);
        gets(course[x]->course_name);
        printf("Print the id number for %s: ", course[x]->course_name);             
        scanf("%d", &course[x]->course_id);                                     
        getchar();
        numbers.number_courses++;                                                                       
        }
    }
if(numbers.number_courses==0)
    {
    courses **course=(courses **)malloc(new*sizeof(courses *));
    if(NULL==course)
        {
        printf("There was a problem in malloc\n");
        exit(3);
        }
    for(x=0; x<new; x++)
        {
        course[x]=(courses *)malloc(sizeof(courses));
        if(NULL==course[x])
            {
            printf("There was a problem in malloc\n");
            exit(4);
            }
        printf("Print the name of course number %d: ", x+1);
        scanf("%s", &course[x]->course_name);
        getchar();
        printf("Print the id for %s: ", course[x]->course_name);
        scanf("%d", &course[x]->course_id);
        getchar();
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", course[x]->course_name, course[x]->course_id, numbers.number_courses, x);
        numbers.number_courses++;
        }
    }
for(y=0; y<numbers.number_courses; y++)
    {
    printf("%d\t%d\n", course[y]->course_id, numbers.number_courses);
    }
return;
```

}

Comment: This line: printf("%d\t%d\n", course[y]->course_id, numbers.number_courses); will always print the same number for 'numbers.number_courses'.  Perhaps you really want to use 'y' instead.

Comment: you have declared courses **course twice, in the outer scope of function `void add_course(void)` and again at the beginning of the then part of `if(numbers.number_courses > 0) { courses **course=(courses **)realloc(`  Also, don't use a cast for realloc, just including <stdlib.h> suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` statements you declare a new local variable `courses` that hides the global variable of the same name:

```
courses **course=(courses **)malloc(....);
```

The print in the end uses the global variable, but that is still `NULL`. You instead want to set the existing global variable:

```
course=(courses **)malloc(....);
```

Comment: The cast should be removed too; this isn't C++.

Comment: So since I had already typedef my struct and globally defined courses **course in the functions, double casting created another  structure definition of the same name set to NULL?

Comment: `courses **courses = xyz;` is a variable declaration. It declares a variable named `courses` of type `courses**`that gets initialized with `xyz`. So at the point where you call `malloc` you accidentally declared a new local variable and used that. The global `courses` variable isn't involved in that line. Aside of that, the cast on the right side, the `(courses**)` in  `(courses**)malloc(...)` isn't necessary, but it also doesn't do any harm and isn't important for the error.